# Minimize the maximum value of dynamically built array

Tags: algorithm, optimization, dynamic-programming, backtracking

I have `n` blocks , each of them is represented by it its height, i.e `block[i]` is a height of `i`.Need to build `k` towers, in such a way that maximum tower height should be minimized. I`ve implemented by backtracking ..Its space is `O(k*n)` and time `O(power(k,n))`. Looking for a better solution...
UPD:This is backtracking solution

```
int MaxWeight(vector<int> blocks, vector<int> heights, int curBlock,int& maxH)
{
    
    if (curBlock == blocks.size())
    {
        int maxHF = 0;
        for (int h : heights)
        {
            maxHF = max(maxHF, h);
        }
        return maxHF;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < heights.size();++i)
    {
        vector<int> heightsTemp = heights;
        heightsTemp[i] += blocks[curBlock];
        maxH = min(maxH, MaxWeight(blocks, heightsTemp, curBlock + 1, maxH));
    }
    return maxH;
}
int FindMaximum(vector<int> blocks, int k)
{
    vector<int> h(k, 0);
    int maxH = 0;
    for (int b : blocks)
    {
        maxH += b;
    }
    int ans = MaxWeight(blocks, h, 0, maxH);
    return maxH;
}
int main()
{
    vector<int> blocks = { 1,2,3,4,5,10,20 };
    int ans = FindMaximum(blocks, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What have you tries / researched so far? Where exactly did you get stuck? Share your ideas / findings / code.

Comment: @MrSmith42 - the code is added. As I explained it is backtracking solution having complexity as mention before